# Any way to mount hard drive (to linux) that already has files on it?

Tags: linux, mount

I have recently installed Ubuntu MATE on my PC (goodbye windows!), and I at first only installed Ubuntu MATE to the ssd (I didn't have my hard drive plugged in when I did the install). Is there any way that I can mount the hard drive without losing the files on it (I already took all the stuff off that I *really* care about, but it would be kind of nice to get the rest. If it is not possible to mount it without losing my files, then how do I mount it anyway? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Here is the error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb3 at /media/bendurham441/Main Storage:
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o 
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb3" "/media
/bendurham441/Main Storage"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The 
disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I also found this thread (https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation) which seems like it might be the answer to my question, so I will try it out and report back to this thread with the results.

Answer (score 1):

It couldn't be easier, in most cases. If an SSD, HDD, flash drive or memory card is plugged in, Ubuntu should list it in Files (nautilus) or other file manager. Simply click on the partition and it will be mounted. [If you wish, it can be mounted on booting.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)

If that fails, use gparted to check the properties of the partition. By default, Ubuntu can read and write to ext(n), NTFS, FAT32 and other formats, but if it's exFAT, then just [install the drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working).

[After error given, above] hiberfil.sys is still on the drive. To prevent damage to the NTFS partition, Ubuntu refuses to mount the drive. You have a few options:

1. Mount the drive in Windows, disable hibernation in that OS, and shut down *completely* (not hybrid shutdown), e.g. by entering in an **elevated** CMD:

> powercfg -h off
>
> shutdown /s /t 0

2. [Mount the drive read-only:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204166/how-do-i-mount-a-hibernated-ntfs-partition) In Ubuntu Terminal, enter:

> sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda5 /media/*Volume ID*

3. Blow away *hiberfil.sys* in Ubuntu (this would prevent recovery of your last Windows session, which from your description seems OK):

> sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sde2 /media/*Volume ID*

If you have further troubles, see [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384429/cannot-remove-hiberfile-on-ntfs-partition) for help.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't do this before but refer back to my post and see what the error is. It is a NTFS partition, to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with why this is happening. If Windows is hibernating and files are changed, weird things happen, potentially including data corruption when you next reboot.

With mount, you'd want to use the ro option (if file recovery is your main aim). If for some reason you wanted to *write* to the disk, use `-f`. This may be risky so using read only (or ro) is the smart option

The refusal to mount the disk is NTFS 3G being *very* polite and refusing to do anything mildly risky, combined with modern versions of Windows (10) using a fastboot/fast restart method similar to hibernation.